# Custom lambda expression not being applied

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a method that is designed to check if a List of strings is contained within a List of column names in a table. Here is the method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ContainsQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames, IEnumerable<string> propertyValues)
        {
            ParameterExpression entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "entity");
            MethodInfo containsInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            MethodInfo toLowerInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[] {});
            BinaryExpression masterExpression = Expression.Or(Expression.Constant(true, typeof(Boolean)), Expression.Constant(true, typeof(Boolean)));
            ConstantExpression negativeOne = Expression.Constant(-1, typeof(int));

            foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
            {
                foreach (var propertyValue in propertyValues)
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    ConstantExpression valueExpression = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
                    ConstantExpression caseInsensitiveComparisonExpression = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, typeof(StringComparison));
                    MemberExpression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(entity, propertyInfo);
                    MethodCallExpression propertyLoweredExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, toLowerInfo);
                    MethodCallExpression valueLoweredExpression = Expression.Call(valueExpression, toLowerInfo);
                    MethodCallExpression containsExpression = Expression.Call(propertyLoweredExpression, containsInfo, valueLoweredExpression);
                    masterExpression = Expression.Or(containsExpression, masterExpression); 
                }
            }
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(masterExpression, entity);
            return query.Where(lambda);
        }
```

I am using it like so:

```
qry = QueryExpressions.ContainsQuery(qry, searchCols, new List<string> {universalSearch});
```

As I step through the code, `qry` starts out as an IQueryable `select all` statement. Then this method gets called and I check `lambda` and it is a nested list of or's as I expect. When I step out of the method though, `qry` remains a simple `select all` statement as before. My lambda expression is not being applied. No matter what I pass in as `universalSearch`, the qry returns the entire data set.

Thanks in advance.

Here is lambda after the method is finished executing:

```
{entity => (entity.STAKE_COMMENT.ToLower().Contains("other".ToLower()) Or (entity.NOTES.ToLower().Contains("other".ToLower()) Or (entity.COMMENT_SOURCE.ToLower().Contains("other".ToLower()) Or (entity.STAKE_COMMENT_DATE2.ToLower().Contains("other".ToLower()) Or (entity.COMMENT_STATUS.ToLower().Contains("other".ToLower()) Or (entity.COMMENT_CATEGORY.ToLower().Contains("other".ToLower()) Or (entity.COMMENTTOPIC.ToLower().Contains("other".ToLower()) Or (entity.STAKEHOLDER.ToLower().Contains("other".ToLower()) Or (True Or True)))))))))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that your query is unchanged but that your predicate is flawed.

You have this as predicate:

```
... lots of stuff ... Or (True Or True)
```

Every condition that contains `or true` will *always* evaluate to true.